# Lógica de Fila - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou com uma dúvida em uma questão, e espero que vocês possam me ajudar, a dúvida em si não é na forma de desenvolver a questão, isso não é o problema, o problema está na lógica da questão que eu não estou conseguindo entender, a questão é a seguinte:

> A legislação em vigor obriga os bancos a iniciarem o atendimento a um
>   cliente em no máximo 20 minutos após a entrada do cliente na fila
>   única da agência bancária. A fila é única, assim um caixa livre
>   solicita ao primeiro cliente da fila que venha ao seu guichê para ser
>   atendido. (Vamos ignorar aqui o problema dos clientes prioritários,
>   idosos, gestantes, portadores de necessidades especiais, etc.) Estamos
>   supondo também que nenhum caixa atende dois clientes ao mesmo tempo.
>
> Seu programa receberá o número de caixas ativas na agência, o número
>   de clientes e, para cada cliente, duas informações, a saber, o momento
>   de entrada do cliente na fila, e a duração do atendimento daquele
>   cliente. Inicialmente todos os caixas estão vazios, já que a agência
>   acabou de abrir. Seu problema é determinar o número de clientes que
>   esperarão mais de 20 minutos para ter seu atendimento iniciado.

Entrada:

> A primeira linha da entrada contém dois inteiros separados por um
>   espaço em branco. O primeiro, C, é o número de caixas ativas na
>   agência bancária. O segundo, N, o número de clientes que procurarão
>   atendimento na agência naquele dia.  As próximas N linhas terão cada
>   uma informações sobre um cliente, consistindo de dois inteiros, T e D,
>   separados por um espaço em branco. O inteiro T fornece o momento em
>   que o cliente entra na fila, em minutos, a partir do instante de
>   abertura da agência. O inteiro D fornece, em minutos, o tempo
>   necessário para atender o cliente. As linhas estão ordenadas por
>   entrada dos clientes na fila.
>
> Suponha:
>
> 1 <= C <= 10 1 <= N <= 1000 0 <= T <= 300 1 <= D <= 10

Saída:

> A saída deverá conter apenas uma linha, contendo um único inteiro, o
>   número de clientes cujo atendimento será iniciado mais do que 20
>   minutos após sua entrada na fila.

A entrada que ele dá é a seguinte:

1 5 - 0 10 - 0 10 - 1 10 - 2 10 - 30 10

Sendo o 1 o total de caixas ativos, 5 o total de clientes, e o demais a hora de chegada do cliente e o tempo que ele vai levar pra ser atendido respectivamente.

E a saída nesse caso é 1.

Então, vamos lá, pelo que eu entendi nesse caso o primeiro elemento da fila não teria tempo de espera, seria atendido diretamente, o segundo iria esperar os 10 primeiros do primeiro, por terem entrado juntos, o terceiro iria esperar os 10 minutos do primeiro, porém por ter chegado no minuto 1 iria esperar apenas 9 do segundo, totalizando 19 correto?
A partir daqui eu começo a me enrolar, o quarto, iria esperar os 30minutos dos 3 primeiros, porém por ter chegado no minuto 2 iria esperar 28min? No caso ele seria o cliente que iria estourar?
O ultimo iria chegar no minuto 30 porém como o tempo estaria em 28min ele iria esperar apenas 2min? e se por um caso chegasse um outro cliente no minuto 36 por exemplo como ficaria?
E nesse exemplo, está sendo usado apenas 1 caixa ativo, sendo que é possível ter até 10.

Será que vocês podem me da uma luz na lógica dessa questão, em como essa conta deve ser feita porque to meio perdido.

Answer (score 1):

Veja a seguinte linha do tempo.

```
(12)-(123)-(1234)--------( 234)----------( 34)----------( 45)----------( 5)----------( )
 ^^     ^      ^          1               2              3 ^            4              5
```

- Cada traço é um minuto que se passou
- Entre parênteses está a fila de clientes (o mais à esquerda está sendo atendido)
- A linha de baixo indica quem entrou (com `^`) e quem saiu (baixando o número)

Analisando os eventos:

- No minuto zero, o primeiro e o segundo cliente entraram e o primeiro começou a ser atendido
- Passou-se 1 minuto
- No minuto 1, o terceiro cliente entrou
- Passou-se 1 minuto
- No minuto 2, o quarto cliente entrou
- Passou-se 8 minutos
- No minuto 10, o primeiro cliente saiu e o segundo começou a ser atendido
- Passou-se 10 minutos
- No minuto 20, o segundo cliente saiu e o terceiro começou a ser atendido
- Passou-se 10 minutos
- No minuto 30, o terceiro cliente saiu, o quarto começou a ser atendido e o quinto entrou
- Passou-se 10 minutos
- No minuto 40, o quarto cliente saiu e o quinto começou a ser atendido
- Passou-se 10 minutos
- No minuto 50, o quinto cliente saiu

Calculando o tempo de espera:

- Cliente 1 esperou 0 minutos (entrou no minuto 0, foi atendido no minuto 0)
- Cliente 2 esperou 10 minutos (entrou no minuto 0, foi atendido no minuto 10)
- Cliente 3 esperou 19 minutos (entrou no minuto 1, foi atendido no minuto 20)
- Cliente 4 esperou 28 minutos (entrou no minuto 2, foi atendido no minuto 30)
- Cliente 5 esperou 10 minutos (entrou no minuto 30, foi atendido no minuto 40)

Ou seja, o cliente 4 foi o único que esperou mais de 20 minutos, por isso a saída do programa é 1.